# Why are text objects not mesh objects?

Tags: mesh, text-object

Why are text-objects *text objects*, and why can they not be calculated like mesh objects? Why is Blender not able to calculate text-objects like mesh objects? If there is a way to completely edit a text-object as a mesh, but keep it a text, or some add-on to do the same thing, could you please tell me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has to do with specific font properties.
And also copyright rights :).

1. Modern computer fonts *don't have fixed proportions* like meshes do.
   They're ever so slightly adjusted when you scale them up/down, to look *optically* correct.
2. In low resolutions, they also take advantage of [hinting data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting), to avoid pixel distortion.
3. Good fonts also contain *kerning data*. This tells them how much space to put between different character pairs. And allows for [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature).

When you convert text to mesh/rasterize it, it loses all of these important features.
That's why some font creators *explicitly prohibit* rasterizing.

---

*Font characters slightly change when scaled, to keep their legibility*
[image]

*Ligature - joining two glyphs into one. Not possible to execute with rasterized text.*
[image]

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font how often "_bezier curve_" appears in refernce to some font types.... understandably the  font objects data part is a curve of type `'FONT`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for doesn't sound possible, a text object is based off the type face you are using if you want to edit it, it'll will have to be converted into a curve or mesh. If you want to keep as a text object and still be able to manipulate it some how you can still apply modifiers to it or mess around with the Geometry settings in the object data tab.